# In a MVC system, where I put my classes that are not part of MVC?

Tags: php, directory-structure

For example: I have a session class, a message class, a CRUD class, in which folder I put them?

my folder structure is:

```
app/    <-- MVC logic
config/ <-- config files
core/   <-- core files of application, such as init
public/ <-- index and assets
vendor/ <-- for composer packages
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the message class? Is the CRUD class some kind of "Table Gateway" or a "Repository"?

Comment: the purpose of message class is warn user possible errors, like wrong email/password, and other stuffs like this, is class session based class.

Comment: I typically put things like this in a repository in my Github account and manage them in my project via composer. They will end up in your vendor directory this way.  It’s a good way to start building manageable and reusable code across projects.

Comment: I understood Robert, a package with my code, that can be reusable.

Comment: The message class is a (form) validation class, right?

Comment: yes it is, but I think that has more others types of implementation, but the main objective is guide user to use the system "correctly"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [Standard PHP package skeleton](https://github.com/php-pds/skeleton) as a good root-level directory structure.

```
config/              # Configuration files
docs/                # Documentation and examples
public/              # Web server files (and front controller)
resources/           # Other resource files (assets, locales, migrations)   
src/                 # PHP source code  (The App namespace)
tests/               # Test code
```

Extended version:

```
vendor/              # Reserved for composer (don't touch this folder)
tmp/                 # Temporary files
tmp/cache/           # Cache files
tmp/logs/            # Log files
```

MVC directory structure (example):

```
templates/           # Templates (HTML, Twig files)
src/Controller/      # Controllers and actions, also src/Action
src/Domain/          # Business logic
```

I think your Session class is a HTTP Session library and the Message class is a validation class (or library). For this reason it should be installed via `composer` into the `vendor/` folder.

It think your "CRUD" class is some kind of a "[Data Table Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html)" or DAO or Repository and could be a combination of an external library `vendor/` and application specific code `src/`.

Comment: Well, I was expecting answers like this. Daniel do you have any documentation for purposes of study? This structure seems more complex that others I looked.

Comment: Keep in mind, there is nothing "standard" about what pmjones writes.

Comment: @MatheusBattisti The most frameworks have their own "opinion" about where to place the specific classes and files. At the moment there is no standard or "MVC the right way".

Answer (score 0):

What is "core" and "init"? Have you learned about MVC some abomination like CodeIgniter or something?

The "crud classes" (which actually should be [data mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)) are part of model layer, same would apply to [domain objects](http://wiki.c2.com/?DomainObject), repositories, services and other cod, that is strictly for implementing domain business logic.

The .. emm ... "session class" should probably do in the vendor, since there are dozens of implementations for session abstraction already available. And I have no idea what "message class" is supposed to be, but if you means "request" and "response", then those too should go in the vendor. I would recommend installing Symfony's [HttpFoundation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation.html) standalone component for those features.

Comment: well I learned MVC searching about, its not based in any framework. The main idea behind this is making some structure to understand how a MVC framework works, like Zend, Laravel, etc.
.
core is a folder that cointains main files of app, ex: init, that is a kind of system bootstrap.
.
and I will take a look in Sinfony.

Comment: @MatheusBattisti most of what you refer to as "core" should be composer packages: stuff like routing, http abstraction, di containers, even ORM (if you really think you need one). As for directory structure .. well, this is what I use in my latest project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2pYf.png

Comment: Yes, like Robert said above, its a kind of package, I will implement this logic. And in this projects I am not using ORM yet, just autoloader PSR-4. I will see your structure.